# Format a string to display the Date correctly

Tags: c#, datetime, string, formatting, iformatprovider

I need help converting this string **-->** `20090727 10:16:36:643` ***to*** **-->** `07/27/2009 10:16:36`

The original date and time are being returned by the `SynchronizationAgent.LastUpdated()` function, which returns a String in the above format.

---

### Original question:preserved for reference

I have this **-->**

```
 HUD.LastSyncDate = mergeSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.LastUpdatedTime;
```

Which is setting a property that looks like this **-->**

```
public static string LastSyncDate
    {
        get { return _lastSyncDate; }
        set
        {
            _lastSyncDate = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:G}", value);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, with or without the `String.Format` the date that is displayed looks like this **-->** `20090727 10:16:36:643`

I have tried multiple variations to Format it the way I want.  What am I missing?

Based on the below suggestions(*Mostly Joel's*), I implemented the suggested changes but I am still getting a `"String is not a valid DateTime error"`

I also tried implementing this -->

```
HUD.LastSyncDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mergeSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.LastUpdatedTime,"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that LastUpdatedTime is actually a string (since you can do the assignment) not a DateTime.  In that case, the format applied won't do anything.  You'll want to parse the LastUpdatedTime into a DateTime then reformat into the format that you want before assigning it to your string.

```
DateTime lastUpdated = DateTime.Parse( mergeSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.LastUpdatedTime );
HUD.LastSyncDate = string.Format( "{0:G}", lastUpdated );

public static string LastSyncDate { get; set; }
```

Note that you may need to use ParseExact instead.

```
DateTime lastUpdated = DateTime.ParseExact( "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:fff",
                                            ...,
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Comment: I tried your ParseExact suggestion and I get the same error as what I posted in Joel Coehoorn's comment section.

Comment: Is the last component of the date using a colon or period separator?  You might have to adjust my format string if it's using a period separator.  Your question showed a colon so I used that, but typically it would be a period for the fractional seconds.

Comment: The period was the issue.  I got it now using a combination of your ParseExact suggestion and Joel's Property suggestion.  Since he has more votes I guess you get the credit.  Would be kind of nice to mark multiple answers, sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

```
HUD.LastSyncDate = DateTime.Parse(mergeSubscription.SynchronizationAgent.LastUpdatedTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

You can put any [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you want there.  But it sounds like what you really want is something more like this:

```
private static DateTime _lastSyncDate;
public static DateTime LastSyncDate
{
    get { return _lastSyncDate; }
    set { _lastSyncDate = value;}
}

public static string LastSyncDateString
{
    get { return LastSyncDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }
}
```

Keep it as a datetime in the background and just use the string property for display.

Comment: I think my problem is that the Format of the String return by LastUpdatedTime is weird --> `20090727 10:45:49.990` and it errors out saying "String was not recognized as a Valid DateTime"

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? You get a string, pass it to `String.Format()` and store it in a string field. Do you want to reformat the string? In this case you have to parse the string back to `DateTime` and format this value again.

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateTime))
{
    lastSyncDate = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:G}", dateTime);
}
else
{
    HandleInvalidInput(value);
}
```